# show array elements in listbox c#

Tags: c#, listbox

Hi I'm trying to see the elements of an array in a listbox, my array is in a class, but I dont know how to see the elements of the array in a windows form listbox.
This is my code:

```
 NumSepaERG[0] = Convert.ToDouble(columnas[1]);
 ListBox listbox2 = new ListBox();
 listbox2.Items.Add(NumSepaERG[0]);
```

But I know how view the elements in the listbox.

Comment: Do you want to know how to display the new ListBox in Form?

Comment: Hi, Mithrandir yes I believe so..

Comment: Each Form has a property named Controls which gives you access to the "list" of it's child controls. Simply add your ListBox to this collection.

Comment: this code is in a class named Import, i want to see the values of NumSepaERG in a windows form Listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
// add items 
listBox1.Items.Add(NumSepaERG[0]);
// add to controls 
Controls.Add(listBox1);
```

if you have array as items then you can use AddRange method as:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(NumSepaERG);
Controls.Add(listBox1);
```

## Update

create object of your class which contain array...

e.g. :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        listBox1.DataSource = obj.NumSepaERG;
        Controls.Add(listBox1);
    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public double[] NumSepaERG { get; set; }
    public MyClass()
    {
        NumSepaERG =new double[] {2.0, 5.6};
    }
}
```

Comment: NumSepaERG is on a class named Import, and I want to see the elements of NumSepaERG on a listbox in my windows form..

Comment: Ok, but NumSepaERG contains data from a file that was selected with openfiledialog, that's why is in the Import class

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
var listbox2 = new ListBox();
foreach(var item in columnas)
{
 listbox2.Items.Add(item);
}
this.Controls.Add(listbox2 );
```

Comment: You dont have to create (first line of A.Yakoub code) that listbox. You can use listbox that you already put on you form with "Form Designer".

Comment: Hi IvanL, I new in C# how do I add the listbox to FOrm.controls??

Comment: @Carl you can try with this.Controls.Add(listbox2);

Comment: YourForms.Controls.Add(listbox2)

Comment: My form is named Form1 but doesnt appear Controls, it appear only ControlCollection

Comment: My array columnas is in a class named Import, i wanto to see the elements of columnas in listbox in my Form1. How can I pass the values of columnas to the windows form listbox

Comment: you declare public property in forms who contains your array, public string[] YourArray{get;set;}

Comment: your array in your forms, when you create forms you set your property

Comment: is there a way to use the value of columnas from my import class to windows form?, because of I usea the code above columnas is underlined in red telling me that the variable doesnt exist in the context.

Answer (score 1):

[ListBox.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) implements IEnumerable through [ListBox.ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx) so you can use a foreach to loop over the elements.

```
foreach (var element in listBox2.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(element.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood, I thought the OP wanted to know how to view the elements in the listbox...